# systemtap user string copy fault

Tags: systemtap

I have written a systemtap script to profile a C++ program. In the systemtap script I want to extract a class member.

Here is the c++ class definition:

```
class CFldOrder
{
public:
    ByteArray cust_no;
};

class ByteArray
{
public:
    const char* get_value(){return buf;}
private:
    char* buf[255];
};
```

Here is the code snippet of the systemtap script:

```
probe process("/trade/ans_bu").statement("*@entrust.cpp:6614")
{
    g_custno = @cast(FldOrder, "CFldOrder")->cust_no->buf
}
```

When the script is running, it failed at this probe and said "user string copy fault at addr 0x0000075". I guess it means "@cast(FldOrder, "CFldOrder")->cust_no->buf" is not a valid address.

If I debug this program with gdb and break at the position "entrust.cpp:6614", FldOrder.cust_no.buf is displayed correctly.

How can I fix the script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your identifier `FldOlder` is just a script variable, which stap will interpret as an integer with the initialized value of zero.  The `@cast` expression hides pointer arithmetic to get that `0x00000075` address - which is exactly what you'd get in C++ if you printed `& ((CFldOlder*)0)->cust_no->buf`.

To fix your script, pass `@cast` a valid pointer.  You probably meant the context variable `$FldOlder`.  You may not even need the `@cast` (which works like C++ `reinterpret_cast<>`) if the type of the variable is already `CFldOlder*`.